# Concatenar valor en registros repetidos usando linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp

Tengo una consulta en linq que me devuelve una lista de colonias desde una tabla en SQLSERVER.

```
var todasColonias = (
                from SQLColonias in context.colonias
                where SQLColonias.status.Equals(true)
                select new
                {
                    _idColonia = SQLColonias.id_colonia,
                    _tipoAsentamiento = SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento,
                    _descrColonia = SQLColonias.descripcion
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Necesito concatenar el valor del campo _tipoAsentamiento cuando el valor del campo _descrColonia exista duplicado en cualquier otro registro.

En resumen necesito hacer algo asi:

```
var todasColonias = (
                    from SQLColonias in context.colonias
                    where SQLColonias.status.Equals(true)
                    select new
                    {
                        _idColonia = SQLColonias.id_colonia,
                        _tipoAsentamiento = SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento,
                        _descrColonia = (SQLColonias.descripcion Existe en cualquier otro registro) ? (_tipoAsentaiento + SQLColonias.descripcion) : (SQLColonias.descripcion)
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

La intención es obtener en el campo _descrColonia algo asi:

```
_descrColonia = "HAMBURGO"
_descrColonia = "SANTA ROSA"
_descrColonia = "SAN ANTONIO"
_descrColonia = "(FRACCIONAMIENTO) LA ROSITA"
_descrColonia = "(AMPLIACION) LA ROSITA"
_descrColonia = "CENTRO"
_descrColonia = "LOS ANGELES"
```

En este ejemplo el valor "LA ROSITA" existe en multiples registros, por lo que se le concatena el string correspondiente al campo _tipoAsentamiento.

Se que puedo recorrer la lista posteriormente y aplicar la concatenacion basandome en técnicas como group() o contains(), pero cuando lo he intentado noto el renimiento muy lento, por lo que preferiría hacerlo directamente desde el select, ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estas usando Entity Framework. La solución que te doy a continuación solo está probada con una `List`, pero entiendo que debería funcionar también en tu caso.

```
var coloniasList = new List<Colonias>();
coloniasList.Add(new Colonias() { id_colonia = 0, tipo_asentamiento = "(FRACCIONAMIENTO)", descripcion = "LA ROSITA" });
coloniasList.Add(new Colonias() { id_colonia = 1, tipo_asentamiento = "(AMPLIACION)", descripcion = "LA ROSITA" });
coloniasList.Add(new Colonias() { id_colonia = 2, tipo_asentamiento = "(AMPLIACION)", descripcion = "LOS ANGELES" });

var todasColonias = (
        from SQLColonias in coloniasList
        select new
        {
            _idColonia = SQLColonias.id_colonia,
            _tipoAsentamiento = SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento,
            _descrColonia = coloniasList.Count(x=>x.descripcion==SQLColonias.descripcion)>1? (SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento + SQLColonias.descripcion) : (SQLColonias.descripcion)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Como ves, lo que hago en el caso de `_descrColonia` es contar las veces que aparece en mi lista la descripción que estoy tratando, y si es mas de 1 le añado el tipo de asentamiento.

En tu caso, la consulta debería ser algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
var todasColonias = (
                from SQLColonias in context.colonias
                where SQLColonias.status.Equals(true)
                select new
                {
                    _idColonia = SQLColonias.id_colonia,
                    _tipoAsentamiento = SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento,
                    _descrColonia = context.colonias.Count(x=>x.descripcion==SQLColonias.descripcion)>1? (SQLColonias.tipo_asentamiento + SQLColonias.descripcion) : (SQLColonias.descripcion)
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Intenté aplicar la solución que me describes, pero obtengo el siguiente error
`{"No se pudo traducir la expresión 'Table(colonias).Where(SQLColonias => SQLColonias.status.Equals(True))' a SQL y no se pudo tratar como una expresión local."}`.

Pero gracias a esto pude encontrar la solución lo único que tuve que hacer es otro query que consulta sobre la lista obtenida en el query original, algo asi: `var listaColonias = (from SQLColonias in todasColonias ...... ).ToList()`.

Comment: @JesúsMiraanda si, por eso exprese alguna duda ya que en LINQtoSQL, las consultas deben poder traducirse a un sql válido, mientras que usando una lista como en mi ejemplo funciona correctamente. Me alegro de todas maneras de que te haya dado una pista para resolverlo :)